# Authentication from web view in a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a web backend server that handles web site (html) authentication from email, facebook, google....

Is it a possible option to load the authentication web form into a native web view, intercept the authentication response by native app, and store login state into native app, so the native app will be able then to send REST authorized queries to the backend server?

Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using WKWebView. It has navigation delegate API

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
```

Using the above API, you can check for access token which is coming via cookie.

Objective-c

```
 WKWebsiteDataStore *dataStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore;
 WKHTTPCookieStore *cookieStore = dataStore.httpCookieStore;
 [cookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray<NSHTTPCookie*> *cookieArray) {

      NSString *cookieValue = nil;
      for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieArray) {

            if ([cookie.name isEqualToString:@"access_token"]) {
                 NSString *accessToken = cookie.value;
                }
            }
}];
```

Swift

```
let dataStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore
let cookieStore = dataStore.httpCookieStore
cookieStore.getAllCookies({ cookieArray in

let cookieValue: String? = nil
for cookie in cookieArray ?? [] {

    if (cookie.name == "access_token") {
        let accessToken = cookie.value
    }
}
```

})

This is what I'm doing in our project. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks, this is interesting. Would it work with swift + swiftui ?